# Is there a better way than this to create a character selection and spawner?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the code I have for my spawner object on the level scene:

```
 public float spawnShipID;
 public GameObject basicShip;
 
 void Start()
 {
     if (spawnShipID == 1)
     {
 
         Instantiate(basicShip, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
     }
 }
```

And this is the code I have on a button on the start menu:

```
public float ShipID = 1f;
 public void shipchoice()
 {
     SceneManager.LoadScene("watcherqueen");
     GameObject.Find("playerspawner").GetComponent<spawnplayer>().spawnShipID = ShipID;
 }
```

The reason I am using different floats on the button and the spawner is because I would like to have different buttons spawn different ships.

Using this code, the scene changes (only with the Play button, but not in the build, though that is a question for another time), and the player ship does not spawn. Are there any solutions or better ways I could have done this?

Comment: If you are finding that you are destroying and reusing the same objects often, object pooling is your friend https://www.raywenderlich.com/847-object-pooling-in-unity

Comment: why use a `float` instead of an `enum` for `spawnShipID`?

Comment: Ruzihm, I didn't actually know about that since I'm kind of new, so how would that help exactly?

Comment: See [here](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/enumerations) for more information about using enums in unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [`LoadScene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html), the scene does not fully load until the next frame. Therefore, your `GameObject.Find("playerspawner")` doesn't even find the instance of playerspawner that is in that scene. (And, even if it were the same instance, it wouldn't run through its `Start` again.)

Instead, you should set the variable to something that already exists in the scene currently running, which also will not destroy on load. A Singleton is especially useful for this application. Starting from [this example](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/116010/121653) by PearsonArtPhoto:

```
public class ShipSingleton: MonoBehaviour {
    private static ShipSingleton _instance;

    public static ShipSingleton Instance { get { return _instance; } }


    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance != null && _instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        } else {
            _instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        }
    }

    public int spawnShipID;
}
```

Then in the start menu button:

```
public int ShipID = 1f;
public void shipchoice()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("watcherqueen");
    ShipSingleton.Instance.spawnShipID = ShipID;
}
```

and in the spawner:

```
public GameObject basicShip;
 
void Start()
{
    if (ShipSingleton.Instance.spawnShipID == 1)
    {
        Instantiate(basicShip, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

I used an int for spawnShipID for simplicity, but an [`enum`](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/enumerations) would be better practice, including how it could help avoid entering invalid ids.

Using an enum could look something like this:

```
public class ShipSingleton: MonoBehaviour {
    private static ShipSingleton _instance;

    public static ShipSingleton Instance { get { return _instance; } }


    private void Awake()
    {
        if (_instance != null && _instance != this)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        } else {
            _instance = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
 
 
    public enum ShipType 
    { 
        small, 
        medium, 
        large,
        boss 
    };

    public ShipType spawnShipID;
}
```

Then in the start menu button:

```
public ShipSingleton.ShipType ShipID = ShipSingleton.ShipType.small;
public void shipchoice()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("watcherqueen");
    ShipSingleton.Instance.spawnShipID = ShipID;
}
```

and in the spawner:

```
public GameObject basicShip;
 
void Start()
{
    if (ShipSingleton.Instance.spawnShipID == ShipSingleton.ShipType.small)
    {
        Instantiate(basicShip, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: @spagoni Especially also (and this might explain why it sometimes works and sometimes not) because you should never use `==` for comparing `float` values! Due to floating point imprecision this might sometimes work sometimes fail because the value might be e.g. `0.999999999` or `1.0000000001` so it is never `==` .. an `enum` as mentioned and maybe even in combination with a `Dictionary<YourEnum, GameObject>`  is a way saver solution

Comment: @spagoni I edited my answer and included an example of an enum. Can't test it at the moment so please let me know of any syntax errors.

Comment: @Ruzihm Geez, at this point I should just put you in the credits of the game.
There is only one error, on the button script on line `public Ship` ("shiptype" in your script) `ShipID = ShipSingleton.Ship.BasicShip` ("small" on your script) `;`
The error reads: `The type or namespace name 'Ship' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an  assembly reference?`

Comment: `Ship` should be the same word as what comes after `public enum` - `ShipType` in my example

Comment: It is. I made sure that I changed all of them. Is there something I am missing to reference the enum?

Comment: I can't see your code so it might be best to ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with the code you are currently using.

Comment: Alright I made a [new one] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62581923/solving-a-simple-enum-problem-question-directed-at-a-specific-person)

Comment: Yeah I really don't have the hang of this website yet

Comment: @spagoni no space between the `]` and the `(` ;)